# parsing XML from curl (mobile.de API) won't work

Tags: php, xml, api, curl

there,

I would like to create a homepage and automatically display the ads of mobile.de on it.
For this there is an API from mobile.de:
https://services.mobile.de/manual/search-api.html

I have the right access data and when I start the call via the browser:
https://services.mobile.de/search-api/search?customerNumber=503300

I get this result:

```xml
<search:search-result xmlns:seller="http://services.mobile.de/schema/seller" xmlns:ad="http://services.mobile.de/schema/ad" xmlns:search="http://services.mobile.de/schema/search" xmlns:financing="http://services.mobile.de/schema/common/financing-1.0" xmlns:resource="http://services.mobile.de/schema/resource" xmlns:error="http://services.mobile.de/schema/common/error-1.0">
<search:total>4</search:total>
<search:page-size>20</search:page-size>
<search:current-page>1</search:current-page>
<search:max-pages>1</search:max-pages>
<search:ads>
<ad:ad key="266399529" url="https://services.mobile.de/search-api/ad/266399529">
<ad:creation-date value="2018-11-19T07:53:58+01:00"/>
<ad:modification-date value="2018-11-19T07:53:58+01:00"/>
<ad:detail-page url="https://suchen.mobile.de/auto-inserat/porsche-997-gt3-rs-ruf-4-0-einzelst%C3%BCck-allrad-solms/266399529.html?source=api"/>
<ad:vehicle>
```

Looks good to me!
Now I would like to go through the individual ads and there are problems.
The individual ads are grouped by this line:

```
<ad:ad key="266399529" url="https://services.mobile.de/search-api/ad/266399529">
```

Through my long years of experience and especially through the Internet, I have come to the following code:

```
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', true);
    $process = curl_init("https://services.mobile.de/search-api/search?customerNumber=503300"); 
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml')); 
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password"); 
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
    $return = curl_exec($process); 
    curl_close($process);  
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($return);
    $ns = $xml->children('http://services.mobile.de/schema/ad');
    foreach($ns as $ad) {
        $attributes = $ad->attributes();
        $key = (string) $attributes['key'];

        var_dump($key);
    }
```

Unfortunately I get exactly nothing as an answer, an empty page without error message.

Comment: If that's the full response, I don't think that's valid/complete XML

Comment: I just posted the beginning of the xml file.

Comment: So how exactly are we supposed to debug this if we don't have valid data with which to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have another element in between your root node and the `<ad:ad>` element.  You need to go via the `<search:ads>` element...

```
$ns = $xml->children('http://services.mobile.de/schema/search')->ads
    ->children('http://services.mobile.de/schema/ad');
```

To access the details of the ads, you need to again look at the structure and see what elements you want and what namespace they are in.  So for the text of the category element of each ad, you can use a loop and...

```
$ns = $xml->children('http://services.mobile.de/schema/search')->ads
    ->children('http://services.mobile.de/schema/ad');

foreach($ns as $ad) {
    foreach ( $ad->vehicle as $vehicle )    {
        echo (string)$vehicle->category[0]
            ->children("http://services.mobile.de/schema/resource")
            ->{'local-description'}.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

A couple of things with this is that the `<resource:local-description>` element is in a different namespace, which is why it uses the `->children()` with this other namespace.  Also as the name contains a `-`, you have to access it using `->{'local-description'}` to make it a valid name.

Lastly - as all this will return the element it points to, you should cast it to a string ( using `(string)` at the start) to make sure you end up with just the text from the element.

Comment: Thanks, it works.
But how can I access the sub-elements now?
I'd like to access the subgroup "ad:vehicle" for every existing "ad-key" (i.e. for every single ad) and there again the sub-element "ad:category".
I want to read out this line and get back the string "Sportscar/Coupé" as value.

Here is the link to the xml-file -> http://senzel.boehm-it-service.de/search.xml

Comment: I've added some new code to extract the `resource:local-description` element, if you follow this pattern you should be able to get all the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you might also use an xpath expression using the namespace prefix:

`//search:search-result/search:ads/ad:ad`

For example:

```
$ads = $xml->xpath('//search:search-result/search:ads/ad:ad');
foreach ($ads as $ad) {
    $key = (string)$ad->attributes()->key;
}
```

Comment: Your solution works, too, thank you very much.
But also here I have the same problem, I don't know how to access the sub-elements in the xml tree.
See my answer above.

Comment: is this still working? I tried to var_dump $ads but it only returns "bool(false)"